# Not showing iframe on clicking button

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import Blog from "../../components/dashboard/Blog";
import Course from "./Course";
import EmbedsPage from "./EmbedsPage";

function Coursedetail(props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    console.log(location.state.id)

    var image = location.state.image
    var title = location.state.title
    var discription = location.state.description

    const showurl = () => {

        // <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

        //  <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsDoLVMnmZs&t=2s" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <iframe width="560" className="embed-responsive-item" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RGKi6LSPDLU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        console.log("hii")
        // </div>
    }

    return (
        <>

            <div className="card">
                <h5 className="card-header">Featured</h5>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <img
                        src={image}
                        alt=""
                        style={{ width: "50%" }}
                    ></img>
                    <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{discription}</p>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={showurl}>
                        Watch Now
                    </button>
                    <button
                        href=""
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        style={{ margin: "15px" }}
                    >
                        Save PDF
                    </button>
         
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Coursedetail;
```

Here is my code in react.js and when I click on the watch now button it does not show the iframe on the screen. please help

I am expecting that when the youtube link come from the database it will send to button and show iframe of the link comes from database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a few issues here:

1. The function `showurl` does not return any JSX
2. The `onClick` handler of the `button` is not capable of rendering HTML by itself—you need to use React state management to dynamically render a component.

I have simplified the code down to a simple React App without application-specific code to make it more clear.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function EmbeddedVideo({ src }) {
  return <iframe src={src} />;
}

function App() {
  const src = "https://550d80-5173.csb.app/";
  const [showEmbeddedVideo, setShowEmbeddedVideo] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{showEmbeddedVideo ? <EmbeddedVideo src={src} /> : null}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setShowEmbeddedVideo(true)}>Show Video</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `EmbeddedVideo` component returns an `iframe`. It takes `src` as a prop and passes it to the `iframe`.

The `src` constant in the `App` component stores the URL (`src`) for the `iframe`

`const [showEmbeddedVideo, setShowEmbeddedVideo] = useState(false);` declares two variables: `showEmbeddedVideo` and `setShowEmbeddedVideo`. This uses React state management through the `useState` hook to store a value and then re-render the component when it is updated.

`{showEmbeddedVideo ? <EmbeddedVideo src={src} /> : null}` uses the JavaScript ternary operator. If `showEmbeddedVideo` is `true`, the `EmbeddedVideo` component will be rendered. If it is `false`, nothing will be rendered.

The `onClick` handler is set to a function that changes `showEmbeddedVideo` to `true` by using the `setShowEmbeddedVideo` function which is defined by `useState(false)`.

You can access a working demo here: https://550d80-5173.csb.app/

Hope this helps.

PS: It is best practice to name functions (and components in React because they are functions) in Pascal Case like `CourseDetail`

Comment: This simply demonstrates dynamically rendering a component with state. The iFrame is just the page itself to demo this.